# Creating closures in a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var actions = {
    'view' : function(){alert("view");},
    'history': function(){alert("history");},
    'renewal': function(){alert("renewal");}
}
for(var action in actions){
    $('.' + action).live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(actions[action])
            actions[action]();
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="view" href="#">view</a>
    <a class="history" href="#">history</a>
    <a class="renewal" href="#">renewal</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I think a closure is created, since clicking a link always alerts "renewal" and I am not able to fix it.

Comment: This basic question must account for about 10% of all JavaScript questions here :-)

Comment: Are you referring to "closure" as some sort of error? Because it isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you try using the classname in the click event?

I'm no jQuery expert, but something like this:

```
$('.' + action).live('click', function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 if(actions[this.className])
   actions[this.className]();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed. You can replace

```
for(var action in actions){
    $('.' + action).live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(actions[action])
            actions[action]();
    });
}
```

with

```
for(var action in actions){
    $('.' + action).live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentAction = $(e.target).attr('class');
        if(actions[currentAction])
            actions[currentAction]();
    });
}
```

By the way, the problem is not that there is a closure. Indeed, if there was not a closure, the value of the variable `action` would not be rembered at all! The problem is that all the functions in the loop refer to the **same** variable `action`, that at the end of the loop will have the value `renewal`.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, but to make your solution work:

```
for(var action in actions){
    (function(myAction){
        $('.' + myAction).live('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(actions[myAction])
                actions[myAction]();
        });
    })(action);
}
```

You are going to find out that live is not going to cancel the default action, You are going to want to use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

That's not what happens. Instead, your event handler function references the `action` variable, which will always have the value 'renewal', since that 's the last item in the list after the loop is done. The best way to go about it is to replace the loop with something like that:

```
for(var action in actions) {
    $('.' + action).live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
        if(actions[action]) actions[action]();
   });
}
```